# J2ME: how to test Bluetooth application on emulator?

Tags: java-me, bluetooth

I want to write an application that sends text from one device to another. How can I test it with an emulator on a PC? Is it possible with the [Sun Java Wireless Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Java_Wireless_Toolkit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, at least with version 2.5.2_01

Just launch the emulator 2 or more times, and the phones "find" each other