# How to test bluetooth connectivity between j2me and j2se

Tags: java, java-me, bluetooth

I am working on an application that has two parts: Desktop(using J2SE) & Mobile(using J2ME).
I have found some examples demonstrating the connectivity part but how do I test them on PC(without actually installing the mobile app on a cellphone)?

If I run both J2ME and J2SE programs simultaneously they can't find each other.

The question is similar to this one:
[J2ME: how to test Bluetooth application on emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431826/j2me-how-to-test-bluetooth-application-on-emulator)
but in my case it is PC<->Mobile communication.

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198306/bluetooth-client-server-communication-between-computer-and-mobile-phone) question did not help me because I just want to know 'how to test the app' not 'how to create it'.

I am using Bluecove,
IDE:Netbeans,
Emulator:Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2

Comment: I am using this example: http://www.miniware.net/articles/viewarticle.php?id=22 ..it works fine if I install it on my cellphone but cant test it on pc.